# requirements model and UML

Tags: uml, requirements, requirements-management

I need to create requirements model for my software(first step of software engineering), But I don't know which icon of UML can help me to implement requirements model.

Comment: Please, read any book about modelling with a use of UML. Your questions reveals you have no idea about UML, making your question way too broad for this site.

Comment: UML does not have Requirements. You can use UML Use Case or SysML Requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML is a complete modelling language, with [lots of diagrams](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html).

It is not totally clear what kind of requirements you want to represent:  is it about the structure of your system ?  Or is it its behavior ?  Without further details, it'll be difficult to give the right answer.

Nevertheless,  if you need to start somewhere, usually you would start with the [use case diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-diagrams.html): it shows the system and the expected functions that it shall offer to the actors (users, other systems) in the environment. So, this model gives a clear picture of the main requirements: what the system shall do for which actor.

*Remark:  You mention an icon.  I suppose you mean the icon in a modelling software.  This will of course depend on the software. Usually it's some kind of stick-person with an oval.*